# How to start new Dialog to NEW user? (Microsoft Bot Builder - Proactive Messages)

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using the official example https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages

There is 3 separate examples: one for sending a simple message and two others for starting new dialogs.

In the first example they create new activity then define: receiver, sender, message's text and so on. But in both the 2nd and the 3rd examples they define nothing. They just use data from an original incoming activity, which is in fact just a delayed in time reply to original message. That's even **NOT a true proactive message**. But how to send a true proactive message from child dialog?

So I need something like mixed one from these examples.

My ConversationStarter:

```
public class ConversationStarter
{
    public static async Task Resume()
    {
        string ServiceUrl = "http://localhost:50891";

        ChannelAccount BotAccount = new ChannelAccount(
            name: "Bot", 
            id: "default-bot"
        );

        ChannelAccount UserAccount = new ChannelAccount(
            name: "User", 
            id: "default-user"
        );

        ConnectorClient ForwardClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(ServiceUrl));
        ConversationResourceResponse ForwardConversation = ForwardClient.Conversations.CreateDirectConversation(BotAccount, UserAccount);
        IMessageActivity ForwardMessage = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
        ForwardMessage.From = BotAccount;
        ForwardMessage.Recipient = UserAccount;
        ForwardMessage.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: ForwardConversation.Id);

        using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, ForwardMessage))
        {
            var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
            await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();

            //interrupt the stack
            var dialog =new ForwardDialog();
            task.Call(dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>(), null);

            await task.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            //flush dialog stack
            await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);           
        }
    }
}
```

My dialog:

```
public class ForwardDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Hello, I'm ForwardDialog. I'm interrupting your conversation.");
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Great, back to the original conversation!");
        context.Done(String.Empty); //Finish this dialog
    }
}
```

context.PostAsync() here returns an error: **"ReplyToId" cannot be null**

But it is NOT a reply to any message, so that it just can't has any ReplyToId parameters.

Comment: You need to send a simple message ForwardClient.Send... and based on that message, on the receiver instantiate the dialog.